# When I add an extra virtual function to a derived class, what is the overhead?

Tags: c++

I'm going through Marshall Cline's C++ Faq - specifically [this link about how virtual functions are implemented in the compiler](http://www.parashift.com/c++-faq/dyn-binding2.html).

It seems to be saying that the vptr for a derived class, exists in the base class portion of the object. And when an instance of a derived class is created, another vptr is not created in the derived class part - simply the vptr that already exists in the base class part is initialised to point to the correct vtable.

My question is: what if I declare a virtual function in a derived class, that is not in the base class, what is the overhead? Is there an extra vptr created in the derived class part - or is it still done the same way, i.e. the vptr in the base class part is assigned to point to a particular vtable?

So - to make my question a bit more concrete - in the following example, does the compiler give `Apple` class an extra vtable, because it added `peel_me()` virtual function? (I'm assuming the answer must be yes ). If so, does the compiler give instances of `Apple` another vptr (i.e. on top of the one in it's `Fruit` base class part)?

```
class Fruit {
  public:
    virtual void display();
};

class Apple : public Fruit {
  public:
    virtual void display() { std::cout << "I'm an apple!\n"; }
    virtual void peel_me(); // extra virtual function, that is not in the base class
};
```

I can't seem to find the answer to this anywhere.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Typically:

`Apple` needs its own vtable regardless of whether you add `peel_me` or not, because it needs its override of `display` to be found by virtual calls on instances of `Apple`.

Adding `peel_me` makes that vtable one entry bigger than it otherwise would be -- this additional entry may or may not occupy a significant amount of space compared to the code for `peel_me`, but you'd expect probably not. The vtables of all derived classes of `Apple` are also one entry larger than they would be if there was no `peel_me`.

Instances of `Apple` have a single vptr. It points to the vtable for `Apple`. This table contains entries for all virtual member functions of `Apple`, including those inherited from `Fruit`, and including any that aren't overridden in `Apple` (in which case the vtable entry in `Apple` refers to the implementation in `Fruit`).

Comment: Do Instances of `Apple` contain a vptr in the Apple part, and also a vptr in the `Fruit` part? or just one vptr?

Comment: thanks. Yes, I am just getting confused on the issue that if I access an instance of `Apple` via a pointer to `Apple`, and call `peel()`, is the vptr (which exists in the `Fruit` part of that `Apple`) still accessible? I am probably overthinking.

Comment: @patchwork: yes, the vptr is still accessible because any code that has the definition of the `Apple` class knows that `Apple` is derived from `Fruit` alone. So it knows where to find everything in `Fruit` including the vptr. When you have multiple inheritance and (especially) virtual inheritance, things get less straightforward and then you might find classes with multiple vptrs in each instance.

Answer (score 1):

If the base class already has a virtual function, none.

Only the first `virtual` function declared in a hierarchy chain affects the size of the object, because a pointer to the virtual table is added. Subsequent ones don't.

*This is of course implementation-dependent, but most behave like this.*

Comment: Even if that base class does not declare a virtual `peel_me()`?

Comment: It probably also declares a virtual destructor.  (It probably should, if it doesn't.)

Comment: And of course, all of this only applies to the case of single inheritance.

Answer (score 1):

The compiler usually creates a `vtable` to store pointers to an object's virtual functions.  So adding one usually costs (assuming the base class already *has* virtual functions so the overhead of storing a `vtable` has already been paid) the storage of one more function pointer and a speed impact of dereferencing a pointer for every call to that virtual function.

Answer (score 1):

There's no absolute rule, and it depends on the implementation,
but... If your derived class already overloads at least one of
the virtual functions in the base class, it already has its own
`vtable`; adding a virtual function will add one more entry to
the `vtable` (typically either 4 or 8 bytes).  But since there
should be only one instance of the vtable per process, that's
one pointer in the entire program, which on a modern machine,
can effectively be considered nothing.

Comment: The size of vtables was a very real concern for Stroustrup when he designed C++, and he considered different implementations, trading of the amount of indirection against the size of the vtables... I guess times have changed. :-)

Comment: @KerrekSB: that's fine, implementations of C++ for non-modern machines can chain vtables if they want to, instead of duplicating the whole thing in each derived class. If the questioner is currently located in the 1980's, that's unusual, and I'd expect it to be mentioned in the question ;-)

Comment: Hehe. But the thought process was quite interesting. I think it concerned MI: Store the offset in the vtable, or adjust the pointer in a thunk? The former is faster, but it means you pay the price even if you don't use it. So thunks are the popular implementation for MI now, even though we could probably afford larger vtables now...

Comment: @KerrekSB Thunks don't eliminate the need for vtables, and are only really relevant when there is multiple inheritance.

Comment: @JamesKanze: Well, that's one way of doing MI. Another way would be to always store the offset in the vtable itself, regardless of MI or SI. Then you wouldn't need thunks, but *all* vtables would double in size... That's what was deemed inexcusable.

Comment: @KerrekSB You don't need a thunk if the offset is 0, which is always the case if there is only single inheritance.  (Early CFront did store the offset in the `vtable`, so it never needed thunks.  But because it's impossible to determine whether you need an offset or not at the call site, that meant that _all_ `vtable` had to contain the offset.  The advantage of using thunks is that you don't need anything when the offset is 0; the disadvantage is that it might be a bit slower, since it entails an extra jump.)